# Is every fixed effect a factor in the model?

Tags: mixed-model, controlling-for-a-variable

Participants received one of three sets of instructions and each completed the same two unique questions in a randomized order. I have a 3 (instructions type) x 2 (question) mixed effects model with participant ID as a random effect.

**If I add the order variable (2 levels) to control for its potential effects, is my model still a 3x2, or does this necessarily make it a 3x2x2?**

Comment: Could you provide more details about how your data looks like? Is it right/wrong binary data for each question? Are you trying to estimate some latent trait?

Comment: @Durden thanks for the reply! Each participant gets one of 3 sets of background information (IV1) that we believe will produce different ratings on a 1-10 Likert scale  of favorability for a hypothetical politician based on a story (DV). They complete two blocks (IV2) with one being about a personal scandal and the other being a political scandal. They are randomized to one of two orders (IV3 or covariate?) for those two blocks. We're most interested in the simple effect of IV1. A secondary interest is the interaction between IV1 and IV2.

Comment: Have you looked into [ordinal response models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83980)?